# Convert images to PDF—in many folders, and save output PDFs to relative folders

Tags: pdf

I have more than 30,000 individual .jpg files (scanned historical documents) in about 200 directories (and subdirectories), 24G in total. Each subdirectory holds between 40 and 400 .jpg-files (meaning pages of a larger document). I'd like to use imagemagick with:

```
convert *.jpg <name-of-subdirectory>.pdf
```

to cycle through each subdirectory, in order to create about 200 different PDF files (each between 40 and 400 pages) automatically. The name of the output PDF should be the name of the subdirectory that contains the input JPGs.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you checked out Automator?

Comment: Relevant -- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29869/converting-multiple-image-files-from-jpeg-to-pdf-format